# Exception encountered during context initialization cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:

Tags: spring-boot

This is my code I am not able to solve this .This code is about authentication of spring boot application . I have given the code of a class SecurityConfiguration . Please help me . I tried to solve this many times but it  could not be solved . The bean of ReactiveUserDetailsService is not getting constructed.

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

private final ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;

private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;

public SecurityConfiguration(
    ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService,
    TokenProvider tokenProvider,
    JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties,
    SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport
) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
    this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager() {
    UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(
        userDetailsService
    );
    authenticationManager.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationManager;
}

@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .securityMatcher(new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(new OrServerWebExchangeMatcher(
            pathMatchers("/app/**", "/i18n/**", "/content/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/test/**"),
            pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
        )))
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .addFilterAt(new SpaWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
        .addFilterAt(new JWTFilter(tokenProvider), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.HTTP_BASIC)
        .authenticationManager(reactiveAuthenticationManager())
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
            .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
    .and()
        .headers()
        .contentSecurityPolicy(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getContentSecurityPolicy())
        .and()
            .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyServerHttpHeadersWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
        .and()
            .permissionsPolicy().policy("camera=(), fullscreen=(self), geolocation=(), gyroscope=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=(), midi=(), payment=(), sync-xhr=()")
        .and()
            .frameOptions().mode(Mode.DENY)
    .and()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/*.*").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/api/auth-info").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .pathMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        // microfrontend resources are loaded by webpack without authentication, they need to be public
        .pathMatchers("/services/*/*.js").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/services/*/*.js.map").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/services/*/v3/api-docs").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .pathMatchers("/services/**").authenticated()
        .pathMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/management/health/**").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN);
    // @formatter:on
    return http.build();
}
```

}

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace.